# Printing empty list

Tags: python-3.x

```
def password_generator():           # generates a password

    chars = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.punctuation
    password = ''
    strength = input("What would you like your password strength to be?(weak/medium/strong) ")

    if strength == "weak":

        letters = [elem for elem in chars.split() if chars.isalpha()] 
        print(letters)
        #for elem in range(10):

         #   password += random.choice(letters)

    return password
```

Why does 'letters' come out to be empty? In the line before `print(letters)`, I assign letters only the alphabetic characters from chars, maybe this is the wrong syntax.

Comment: you probably mean `if elem.isalpha()`

Comment: `chars.split() if chars.isalpha()` makes no sense: `chars` doesn't need to be split, and your condition is always false since `chars` contains symbols.

Answer (score 3):

that

```
letters = [elem for elem in chars.split() if chars.isalpha()]
```

makes no sense at all. `chars.split()` returns a list with `chars` as sole element...

And your condition `chars.isalpha()` is false: it applies to the whole character set...

You probably meant:

```
letters = [elem for elem in chars if elem.isalpha()]
```

If you want letters to be able to perform a `random` on them you can just do:

```
letters = string.ascii_letters
```

demo:

```
>>> string.ascii_letters
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only want alpha characters in letters why not just do this?

```
letters = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase
```